# change lots of file permission if not as per desired

Tags: performance, unix, file-permissions, chmod

A lot of file permission getting changed. there is huge number of file and chmod -R  taking more than 30 minutes. but most of files permission will be as needed.

Changing recursive so that if some file creates with wrong permission that gets fixed.

is there any other more perform way there?

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on the scenario there are at least three things that you can make:

- Add the default ACL (and normal ACL) so some user/groups always have proper access.
- Change file group and SETGID bit to group of users that must have access to the files. Also setting proper mask might be helpful.
- Use audit subsystem, but with huge number of messages it is hard to maintain.

Comment: it needs to do for a directory and the user and group are already fixed. Is there a way that it will change permission only if desired permission is not set.